# For If loop going over same range multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

Context:I have a range of cells where some have the same contents. I am attempting to loop through the cells and take specific actions based on how many times the value finds a match (up to 7). If it helps at all, I want to move certain ranges of information to a different row based on the matches found.

What I've Done: I have it looping over the range, but the problem is that it will hit the same range multiple times.

What I Want: I'd like to to continue the For loop after the matching values end, if possible.

```
For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 1, 4).Value Then                   'Checks first and second levels
            Debug.Print "First and second levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 1, 4).Address & "]"

            If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 2, 4).Value Then           'Checks second and third levels
                Debug.Print "Second and third levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 2, 4).Address & "]"

                If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 3, 4).Value Then       'Checks third and fourth levels
                    Debug.Print "Third and fourth levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 3, 4).Address & "]"

                Else
                    'If Cells(i, 14).Value = "No" Then                        'Only first & second level procedures

                    Debug.Print "Only first and second levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 2, 4).Address & "]"
                End If

            Else
                If Cells(i, 14).Value = "No" Then                           'Only first & second level procedures


                End If
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "No match [" & Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 1, 4).Address & "]"
        End If
     Next i
'End With
End Sub
```

This is what the current Debug.Print output looks like (D8:D11 all match):

First and second levels [$D$8,$D$9]

Second and third levels [$D$8,$D$10]

Third and fourth levels [$D$8,$D$11]

First and second levels [$D$9,$D$10]

Second and third levels [$D$9,$D$11]

Only first and second levels [$D$9,$D$11]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the fix is simple enough: change the *i* integer value based on how many values match. Code below

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 1, 4).Value Then                   'Checks first and second levels
            Debug.Print "First and second levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 1, 4).Address & "]"

            If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 2, 4).Value Then           'Checks second and third levels
                Debug.Print "Second and third levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 2, 4).Address & "]"

                If Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i + 3, 4).Value Then       'Checks third and fourth levels
                    Debug.Print "Third and fourth levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 3, 4).Address & "]"

                Else
                     i = i + 2             '<~~~CHANGE
                    If Cells(i, 14).Value = "No" Then                        'Only first & second level procedures

                        Debug.Print "Only first and second levels ["; Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 2, 4).Address & "]"
                    End If
                End If

            Else
                i = i + 1                     '<~~~CHANGE
                If Cells(i, 14).Value = "No" Then                           'Only first & second level procedures

                End If
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "No match [" & Cells(i, 4).Address & "," & Cells(i + 1, 4).Address & "]"
        End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new sheet2 to save the data.
2. Go through column 4 in sheet1.
3. If you find a match with any column in sheet2 then add the address under that column. Otherwise create a new column with this value in sheet2 and add address under it.